# Change size thumbnails wordpress

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

I want change size thumbnails. I want that width will be 200px and height will be proportional to the width.
In function I added 
`add_image_size( 'featured', 200, 9999);` // create photo with width 200 and proportional height
But for vertical photo, its looks like:

```
<img class="wp-image" width="149" height="200" alt="1349431380_photobomb_02" src="http://wp-r/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/1349431380_photobomb_02-200x267.jpg">
```

how can set this width=200 and height=auto 
I think I should use the function `set_post_thumbnail_size` but I can understand how can set height auto in this function.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have to add code. Go to dashboard Settings/media set width and leave height box empty.

Comment: it works for new added media, for ones already in library you can use regenerate thumbnails plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/